# Detect whether string variations exist in a column

Tags: python, string, data-cleaning

I understand that we can use fuzzywuzzy to clean the variations when we detect them. Well, my question is before the cleaning, is there a standard tool/method that can detect whether the string variations exist or not?

For example, in one column there might be those variations:

```
Red Pen
reD penn
green pencil
0.5 black Pencil
Green  Ppencil
red/ pen
```

I usually just sort the column by the values and see if there are any variations that need to be unified. But I believe there are some more automated ways to do this?